# Check if a selector is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, selector

I have a noob question about jQuery selector. I want to wrap an element after a click, but only if it has a specific class name (".js-loader"), and only if it's an input[type"submit"], or an input[type="button"], or a  or if it got a class name ".form-button" ...

```
var selector = '.js-loader';

$(selector).on('click', function() {
    if( $(this).is(???) ) {
        console.log('Its a submit button or something like that, so its ok.');
    }

    else {
        console.log('You shall not pass.')
    }
});
```

The problem is, I'm a true novice in javascript and jQuery and I just have no idea how to doing this properly.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my english :)

**Edit :**
I want to put those selector in another variable, i'll need them later.

http://jsfiddle.net/fMUc9/

Comment: why dont you add that into selector var..

Comment: Well, i could, but i want to put those selectors in another variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function pass the selectors against which you want to test the element against

```
$(selector).on('click', function() {
    if( $(this).is('input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]') ) {
        console.log('Its a submit button or something like that, so its ok.');
    }
    else {
        console.log('You shall not pass.')
    }
});
```

Comment: not working. the problem is maybe the is() ... i just try with is() but im not sure it's the solution...

Comment: can you share the html sample

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(selector).on('click', function() {
if( $(this).is('input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], a, .form-button') ) {
    console.log('Its a submit button or something like that, so its ok.');
}

else {
    console.log('You shall not pass.')
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(selector).on('click', function() {
    if( $(this).is('input :submit, input :button, a.form-button') ) {
        console.log('Its a submit button or something like that, so its ok.');
    }

    else {
        console.log('You shall not pass.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var selector = '.js-loader';

$(selector).on('click', function() {
   if( $(this).is('input[type"submit"], input[type="button"],.form-button') ) {
        console.log('Its a submit button or something like that, so its ok.');
    }

    else {
        console.log('You shall not pass.')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(selector).click(function() {
    if( $(this).is("input[type=button], input[type=button], a") || $(this).className == 'form-button' ) {
        console.log('Its a submit button or something like that, so its ok.');
    }

    else {
        console.log('You shall not pass.')
    }
});
```